# Group by ForeignKey and get whole object

Tags: python, django, group-by, foreign-keys

I'm making dialog system

```
class Dialog(models.Model):
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="author_customer", blank=False, null=False)
    interlocutor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="interlocutor_customer", blank=False, null=False)
    archive_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_view_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class DialogMessage(models.Model):
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=False)
    dialog = models.ForeignKey(Dialog, blank=False, null=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False)
    message = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='dialogs', blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to get last message by create date for every dialog

```
* Dialog1
    Last Message
* Dialog2
    Last Message
```

I tried to make it like this

```
DialogMessage.objects.values('dialog_id').annotate(last_date=Max('create_date'))
```

But it gives me

```
[{'dialog_id': 1, 'last_date': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 6, 3, 15, 56, 267626, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dialog_id': 2, 'last_date': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 7, 13, 24, 33, 856453, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'dialog_id': 3, 'last_date': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 7, 13, 25, 14, 948088, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]
```

How can i get not only last_date, but whole DialogMessage

In the end i want list of last DialogMessage for every dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
DialogMessage.objects.annotate(last_date=Max('create_date'))
```

Basicly you should specify in `values()` all parameters you want there. You only specified `dialog_id` and `last_date` in annotate.

If you need to use `values()`, use:
`objects.values('dialog_id', 'dialog__create_date', 'dialog__author', ...)`
(to specify parameters of foreign keys you need to seperate them by double underscore `__`)

I also think that having `author` in both models is bad design.